# Find theme or topic by a set of words

Tags: words, word-classes

Is there a way to find a common topic given a set of words?

For example, by giving the words: `blue`, `red`, `green`, the common theme would be `color`, or from `beef`, `hamburger`, `salad`, `sandwich` I would get `food`.

I don't know if there are studies or tools to help with this word categorization

Comment: are you building something or do you want to know if something exists?

Comment: We'll both, if there is a theory and no application I can create something, even better if something exists already

Comment: Checking a thesaurus would be a start, though you'd have to distinguish different senses of most English words, which means at least a little tagging and parsing first.